# Error with await operator

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

There is problem with my code. How can I solve this problem? This problem in await operator.

```
 public MyModel() 
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/video.get?uid=219171498&access_token=d61b93dfded2a37dfcfa63779efdb149653292636cac442e53dae9ba6a049a75637143e318cc79e826149");
        string googleSearchText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject googleSearch = JObject.Parse(googleSearchText);
        IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["response"].Children().Skip(1).ToList();
        IList<MainPage1> searchResults = new List<MainPage1>();
        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            MainPage1 searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainPage1>(result.ToString());
            searchResults.Add(searchResult);

        }
```

Comment: Can you verbalise what the problem is? An error at compile time? At runtime?

Comment: At least, give us the error message!

Comment: And the error message? And the line number?

Comment: I can't change the method to async

Comment: You dont use the `async` operator. Try changing it to `public async MyModel()`.Better give us the error you get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to use `await` within a constructor. You can't do that - constructors are *always* synchronous.

You can only use `await` within a method or anonymous function with the `async` modifier; you can't apply that modifier to constructors.

One approach to fixing this would be to create a *static* async method to create an instance - that would do all the relevant awaiting, and then pass the results to a simple synchronous constructor. Your callers would then need to handle this appropriately, of course.

```
public static async Task<MyModel> CreateInstance()
{
    string googleSearchText;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(...))
        {
            googleSearchText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    // Synchronous constructor to do the rest...
    return new MyModel(googleSearchText);
}
```

Comment: "response" does not exist in the current context

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm getting an error in visual studios `The type or namespace name async could not be found (are you missing using directive or assembly reference`.  I've declared `using System;` and `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: It turns out that I'm using VS2010 and that according to this page https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async async doesn't work with VS2010.

Comment: @nueverest: Right, that would certainly cause that problem... Now would be a good time to upgrade to VS2015...

Answer (score 5):

You can't use await in the constructor of a class.

An async method returns a `Task` object which can be executed async. A constructor does not have a return type and thus can't return a `Task` object, and thus can't be awaited.

A simple fix for this problem is create a Init function:

```
public MyModel() 
{

}

public async Task Init()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/video.get?uid=219171498&access_token=d61b93dfded2a37dfcfa63779efdb149653292636cac442e53dae9ba6a049a75637143e318cc79e826149");
    string googleSearchText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JObject googleSearch = JObject.Parse(googleSearchText);
    IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["response"].Children().Skip(1).ToList();
    IList<MainPage1> searchResults = new List<MainPage1>();
    foreach (JToken result in results)
    {
        MainPage1 searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainPage1>(result.ToString());
        searchResults.Add(searchResult);

    }
}
```

---

Then when you create your model:

```
var model = new MyModel();
await model.Init();
```