# httpClient show me error c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnet-httpclient

I have following code but its show error I am using framework 4.5. please help .

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://private-5e199-karhoofleetintegration.apiary-mock.com/");

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-charset", "utf-8");

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "Basic *sample_token*");

    using (var content = new StringContent("{  \"vehicles\": [    {      \"vehicle_type\": \""+ vehicale_type +"\",      \"vehicle_id\": \"" +vehicle_id+"\",  "\"heading\": 90      }    }  ]}", System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("{supplier_id}/availability?version=2", content))
        {
            string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mark your method as `async`? (ex: `public async void my_method()` ).

Comment: await operator can only be used with async method

Comment: no..i am using simple method and show its above code

Comment: make the method async and return Task or Task<T>

Comment: how ? to async method

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205810/error-with-await-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the async/await stuff you'll need to mark your method with the `async` keyword.

If your method is an event handler then use `async void` and if it's not then use `async Task` or `async Task<ReturnType>`. (make sure you replace "ReturnType" with actual type returned by your method)

**Example:**

```
public async Task GetDataFromTheWeb()
//     ^^^^^ add this keyword
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://private-5e199-karhoofleetintegration.apiary-mock.com/");

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-charset", "utf-8");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "Basic *sample_token*");

        using (var content = new StringContent("{  \"vehicles\": [    {      \"vehicle_type\": \""+ vehicale_type +"\",      \"vehicle_id\": \"" +vehicle_id+"\",  "\"heading\": 90      }    }  ]}", System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("{supplier_id}/availability?version=2", content))
            {
                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If this answer solved your problem then you can mark it as accepted. Happy coding!